# Nvidia drivers macbook pro retina (10,1) 14.04

Tags: nvidia, xorg, suspend, macbook-pro, nouveau

So, I'm currently dual-booting 14.04 and OSX on my macbook pro retina (10,1).

I am currently using the nouveau drivers and have had no luck what-so-ever getting the nvidia drivers to work. What happens is that I install them, generate and Xorg.conf, then reboot, but only get a black screen once I try booting into Ubuntu.

I've tried the `nvidia-current` package from apt, I have tried just using the additional drivers page and switching to the 331 (it says tested), both with no luck.

I want to use nvidia drivers for 2 main reasons:
1) hope of getting suspend to work - it just wakes up to a black screen and I cannot get to terminals via ctrl+alt+F5
2) switching workspaces is sluggish, and i'm hoping there will be a noticeable difference.

After doing some research, it looks like some people have been able to get the nvidia drivers working. 
But I also saw that nvidia drivers do not work when Ubuntu is installed in (U)EFI mode, but only legacy mode (I did not install in legacy mode)

Is there any hope getting the nvidia drivers working?
Can I switch to legacy mode without reinstalling Ubuntu?
Am I just doing something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: Alright, so after research and bashing my head against my desk, it looks like Nvidia drivers will not work in EFI boot. I tried converting to a legacy install, but that just booted me into a grub console. Managed to fix that through boot-repair to get back to where I was. Looks like this is pointless until I reinstall in legacy mode.

Answer (score 1):

**I had the same problem on Mint. Try installing the newest nvidia driver version by doing:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
```

It looks like nvidia-drivers 331-338 (or at least some of them) are not working on Macs with Ubuntu/Mint correctly.

**If it doesn't work you may also need to blacklist the nouveau drivers:**

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Add to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT

```
nouveau.blacklist=1 quiet splash
```

Update:

```
sudo update-grub2 //or grub depends on your version
```

Reboot.

**If you get a blackscreen again you might want to boot up in safe mode or add the nomodeset parameter in the kernel boot parameters**

press `e` in the grub boot menu

Add to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT

```
nomodeset
```

Boot.

**The problems you will have with the Nvidia Drivers are:**

- heating issues
- higher battery drain
- high fan speed

These are related to Optimus/gpuswitching not working on macs with linux.

You can try http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/macfanctld.1.html to adjust your fans to your needs.

Comment: the nvidia driver is hardly the reason for the above problems. Rather that the macbook is using the Nvidia card instead of the Intel card. Thats a GFX card switching issue. Once you switch off the Nvidia card and only use the intel one, you loose these issues

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here - an update came for 'nvidia-current' drivers yesterday, I updated and on reboot -  no display, out of memory messages and crashing, etc.
I am running MacBook Pro (late model) in dual boot set up with 14.04.
One solution that I found to quickly get back and recover is to:

somehow get to the shell
(for me the Cntr+ Alt + F1 never worked on Mac, so in grub boot into recovery mode and find a terminal there).

purge anything to do with nvidia:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

reboot after that and all should came back to "normal" - meaning default drivers.

I also would like to be able to use proprietary nvidia display - but am also at a loss.

and BTW -

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Never had any effect for me in this install - hmmm